# How to convert jpg images to bpg

Tags: image, macos, type-conversion, jpeg, bpg

Does anyone knows how to convert **jpg images to bpg** on a MAC? I'm trying to compare several image formats and I would like to compare the original's with the BPG, but I haven't found how to convert the images for this format.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can install bpgenc on Mac OS X using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install libbpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing of bpg-files is not (yet) supported in Mac OS X. But you can do it yourself using the library http://bellard.org/bpg/libbpg-0.9.5.tar.gz

Some guys tried this for the Mac and it worked (search in google). So it may not be the simplest job to do but it will work. You have to first create an NSBitmapImageRep from the source file. Then you have all data of the image you need to convert and now switch to the library.

Because I am interested in image formats (and bpg looks promising)  I will give it a try.

Comment: I will also give it a try. 
If I manage to get some results I will share them here.
Thank you @Heinrich for your answer.